# Keyboard shortcut to change Right-to-left status in Gmail

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut (or a Greasemonkey script that adds this keyboard shortcut), to make a certain paragraph right-to-left, or left-to-right in gmail?

This [question](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=18c8b30e780cea77&hl=en) in the official gmail forums has no answer.

Comment: @phwd understanding this question requires knowledge in RTL usage of the computer, there's a link to a similar question in the official gmail forums, it was viewed 1K times, so people who speak RTL languages probably. How else can I clarify it?

Comment: +1 for "This question in the official gmail forums has no answer"

Comment: were `ctrl`+`shift`+`x` for me in firefox!

Comment: Anyone knows the answer for Google Inbox? Should I open a new question?

Comment: @haggai_e - there's an open issue about the same RTL problem in INBOX: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/inbox/ZEOL3Qt50bI and the best solution was downgrading :( . My solution was to move back to gmail...

Comment: Thanks @noam manos, but my problem was with the web interface (although I guess mobile state is worse). Anyway, my current solution is to use the mouse and Chrome's context menu to change direction.

Answer (score 6):

Found it!

RTL: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

LTR: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

(I'm on Ubuntu and Chrome)

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Mac, and now gmail deduce directionality by the first letter in the paragraph, so shape isn't so bad.

Comment: Yup, the auto directionality is a nice, but still have some bugs occasionally. I'm On Ubuntu and Chrome, maybe it's specific to this setup.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>RShift</kbd> (as in, the shift and control keys on the right side of the keyboard).  Works for me in Chrome and all other Windows apps.  In Firefox it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

This is for RTL typing, not for right justified text (similar but different).

This the most complete, pedantic answer possible:

To have some paragraphs LTR and some RTL, you need to have rich formatting enabled.  If you don't have rich formatting enabled, the change is temporary and will not be seen on the receiving end of the email.  There is no way to send RTL text without enabling rich-formatting because plain text emails don't support the RTL HTML tags.

Clicking the "Right to Left" button on the rich-formatting toolbar has the same effect as typing <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>RShift</kbd> while rich-formatting is enabled.  Typing <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>RShift</kbd> without rich formatting has only a local effect, unseen at the receiver, and applies to the entire text, not just the current paragraph.

Comment: I should've emphasized that, but I wrote *in gmail*. Fixed now.

Comment: @Elazar, works for me using Chrome in GMail.  I don't think the solution will be limited to GMail.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @rchem, I did, it didn't work for me in Chrome. Did you use rich text editor? Do you have BiDi enabled? Did it really changed the direction of the paragraph, or just aligned it to the right? Try to write "א a", the hebrew letter should be the rightmost one.

Comment: @Eyal please edit your answer so that I can remove the downvote. If it worked for someone, I don't want to keep to downvote an answer that worked for someone.

Comment: @Elazar - downvoting every single answer which does not help you is not proper etiquette. If an answer is not helpful, leave it as it. If an answer is *really* out of line, *then* downvote it.

Comment: @Yuval, the point here is not that it doesn't work for me but work for someone else, but it seems that this answer doesn't answer my question at all, and Eyal didn't bother to test if it really works as I suggested in the comment. This attitude won't bring the community helpful answers. (Eyal describes a way to change the RTL state in windows, which I know, and there's no reason what so ever it'll have any effect on the internal Javascript code in gmail, it might work "temporarily", but it will not add the proper tags).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, on the Google Chrome titlebar, I use <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>RShift</kbd> to change to RTL. Somewhat intuitively, <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>LShift</kbd> changes back to LTR. I find myself accidentally setting to RTL when I'm trying to select (with <kbd>RShift</kbd>+<kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>).

Comment: I want to change directionality in the actual paragraph, not just the visual directionality in a textbox.

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich You're probably going to have to be specific about which software you're using!

Answer (score -1):

using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> should do it

Comment: This doesn't work - it brings up the quick search panel in Firefox and in Chrome.